# PySpark: Check if the values in some columns are within a range

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

Assuming that I have the following Spark Dataframe:

```
+---+--------+-----+----+--------+
|c1 |   c2   |  c3 | c4 |   c5   |
+---+--------+-----+----+--------+
|  A|   abc  | 0.1 |null|  0.562 |
|  B|   def  | 0.15| 0.5|  0.123 |
|  A|   ghi  | 0.2 | 0.2|  0.1345|
|  B|   jkl  | null| 0.1|  0.642 |
|  B|   mno  | 0.1 | 0.1|  null  |
+---+--------+-----+----+--------+
```

How can I check whether all of the values in the last 3 columns are within range `[0, 1]` if they are not `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
from functools import reduce
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import warnings

# Filter out valid values
test_df = df.where(reduce(lambda x, y: x | y,  ((F.col(x) > 1) | (F.col(x) < 0) for x in df.columns[2:])))

if not len(test_df.head(1)) == 0:
    test_df.show()
    warnings.warn('Some of the values in the final dataframe were out of range')
```